# URLSession.dataTask is timing out on every request with Xcode 12.5 Beta 2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, urlsession

I upgraded to the latest Xcode 12.5 Beta 2 today, and now all of my URLSession.dataTask requests are failing and timing out. I create a sample project that makes a simple request, but it's failing each time. It works find with Xcode 12.5 Beta 1.

Here's a simple request:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/8863.json?print=pretty") else { fatalError() }

let startTime = Date()

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    let requestTime =  Date().timeIntervalSince(startTime)

    print("Time for request: \(requestTime)")

    if let error = error {
        updateLabel("requestTime: \(requestTime)\nError: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
    guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
          (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
        updateLabel("requestTime: \(requestTime)\n\(response.debugDescription)")
        return
    }
    if let mimeType = httpResponse.mimeType, mimeType == "text/html",
       let data = data,
       let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(string)
            //                    self.webView.loadHTMLString(string, baseURL: url)
        }
    }
}
task.resume()

func updateLabel(_ text: String) {
    print(text)
}
```

Is anyone else on the beta having this same issue?

Comment: This seems to be simply a bug in Xcode 12.5 beta 2. We'll be moving back to an earlier release until this is fixed.

Comment: Same problem - Timeout on 12.5 beta 2, ok on 12.4

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I got the same Issue and Im struggling with it. It's seems there is nothing wrong with your code. Probably is some permission on xcode. Be sure to have added this line in info.plist [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wH6TE.png)

Comment: This is only required for non-HTTPS requests. My code is also failing in a Playground, so this is not the issue.

Comment: Yeah, not working for me either. We'll have to wait for Apple to release the next beta unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved in Xcode 12.5 Beta 3